# DataTables auto refresh function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, refresh

I have an issue with the reload function for DataTables.

I am using the following code to load and reload the table (server-side).

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#dienst_tabelle').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "getData.php",
        "serverSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bPaginate":false,
        "searching": false,
        "paging": false, 
        "info": false,
        "columns": [
            { mData: 'dienstname' } ,
            { mData: 'tagesart' },
            { mData: 'gueltig_am' },
            { mData: 'dienstbeginn' },
            { mData: 'dienstende' },
            { mData: 'zeit' },
            { mData: 'status' },
            { mData: 'button' }
        ]
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#dienst_tabelle').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
    }, 3000);
});
```

The table loads successfully, but the reload-function doesn't do anything...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check in devTools if requests to server are being sent?

Answer (score 0):

I can recreate your problem, if I don't handle the [server-side `draw` parameter](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) correctly.

The documentation for this parameter states:

> *The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the draw parameter sent as part of the data request.*

Every time DataTables sends a request to the server it will increment this integer counter (starting at 1).  It is the server's job to ensure that the `draw` parameter it sends back in its response corresponds to the parameter it received in the request.

So, for example, if you hard-code the `draw` parameter on the server to `1`, then the request generated by `setTimeout` will have a `draw` value of `2` and the server will respond with a `draw` value of `1`. This mismatch will result in the response being received, but ignored by DataTables.

**The solution** is for your server-side code to retrieve the `draw` value from the request and return that same exact value (as an integer) in the response. You are using PHP, which I do not use - so either you already know how to access request parameters using PHP, or you may need to research that.

(In your case, where you are using `GET`, then maybe you need to use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` in your PHP.)